# Wrong database query design guidelines

Tags: mysql

One of the guidelines of querying database is to do the max you can in 1 query and not splitting it, Because even if it would result in few joins, the query optimizer will optimize that off.
Then I noticed a query resulting 1 row was taking 1.5 sec and I checked why is that.
The query was like

```
SELECT a.b FROM a, c WHERE a.d = c.e AND c.f = 'g'
```

While I knew `c.f = 'g'` matches one row, I thought that as the guidelines say, the query optimizer will catch it. Well, it didn't.
Splitting this to two queries which first one retrieves `c.e` and second one uses that to retrieve `a.b` reduced time to few milliseconds.
I have `a.d` foreign key of `c.e` and, mentioned columns except `a.b` uniquely indexed, both tables have about 2 mil rows and I use `MySQL` with `InnoDB`.
Is it really a problem with the guidelines or I understood something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

- Also consider whether INDEXE's are available on a.d, c.e, c.f
- Use the query profiler to further refine your queries based on your particular requirements: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

And also remember that you can improve performance in other ways too like query cache, OS tuning etc: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips